# How can I get password text box for django?

Tags: python, django, forms, input, passwords

```
class Users(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    password_token = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='0')
```

The password text input field is regular text input field. It's not password field.

How can I get password field in django?

I tried `password = models.CharField(max_length=300, widget=forms.PasswordInput )` but got error.

Comment: What error did you get? "got error" tells us nothing.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715103/password-field-in-django-model) out

Comment: [Overriding default widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets)

Comment: @ChrisPratt, http://pastebin.com/8VZPWCQz , <= error

Comment: @jere, can't understand what to do?

Comment: @guru, i think i didn't get your question quite right. what i was talking about was a way to store passwords in an encrypted way instead of plain text, like django does by default. it's kinda messy anyway, hope you figured it out already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way if you have a forms.py in your app is to specify the widgets in your class Meta e.g.

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, PasswordInput
class UserForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Users

        widgets = {
            'password' : PasswordInput(),
        }
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do the same thing in `class Users(models.Model): password = models.CharField(max_length=300)
` ?

Answer (score 3):

Widgets are assigned in the forms, not on the model.

Please see the docs for forms documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach. Create a file named forms.py inside your app.

for example:

```
from django import forms
from models import Users

class UsersForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Users
```