# How to hide password in QLineEdit

Tags: python-2.7, passwords, pyside, qlineedit

Want to hide password typed by "*". But the password is appearing as original text...

```
class Form(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Form,self).__init__(parent)

        self.usernamelabel = QLabel("Username : ")
        self.passwordlabel = QLabel("Password : ")
        self.username = QLineEdit()
        self.password = QLineEdit()
        self.okbutton = QPushButton("Login")
        self.username.setPlaceholderText("Enter Username Here")
        self.password.setPlaceholderText("Enter Password Here")

        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.usernamelabel,0,0)
        layout.addWidget(self.passwordlabel,1,0)
        layout.addWidget(self.username,0,1)
        layout.addWidget(self.password,1,1)
        layout.addWidget(self.okbutton)
        self.setLayout(layout)
```

Comment: this post will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715103/password-field-in-django-model/3715382#3715382

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `QLineEdit` class has [several modes](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#EchoMode-enum) which allow you to control how its text is displayed. To show only asterisks (`*`), do this:

```
self.password = QLineEdit()
self.password.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
...
output = self.password.text()
```

PS:

To set a different password character, you can use this stylesheet property:

```
self.password.setStyleSheet('lineedit-password-character: 9679')
```

The number is a unicode code point, which in this case is for a black circle (`●`).

Comment: " self.password = QLineEdit() "
 What should I modify in this code to get  output.?

Comment: @AniruddhChaudhari. `output = self.password.text()`.

Comment: now working bro!! Any other method? " Self.password = ____________() " like this.? Anything between space

Comment: @AniruddhChaudhari. A method for what? (PS: if you found this answer useful, please accept it - i.e. click the tick symbol).