# How to encrypt a password field in django

Tags: python, django, encryption, passwords

I have a model with name, code and password. I need to encrypt the password. Also I should'nt show a plain text in the password field. 
I referred to this link

[Password field in Django model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715103/password-field-in-django-model)

But the answer is old and need to know what the present approach is.

My model is as below

```
class Crew(models.Model):
    crew_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    crew_code = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, unique=True)
    crew_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    crew_password = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in your view

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
crew_password = 'take the input if you are using form'
form = FormName(commit=False)
form.crew_password=make_password(crew_password)
form.save()
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very useful to me.

Answer (score 6):

Add this to your model:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.crew_password = make_password(self.crew_password)
    super(Crew, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And to hide the text in the password field, in your form:

```
password = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.PasswordInput
)
```

Comment: Just a small modification: 
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.write_key = make_password(self.write_key)

Answer (score 1):

Django added PasswordInput widget use that to make password field in your template

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, PasswordInput

class CrewForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Crew
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'crew_password': PasswordInput(),
        }
```

Also as @Exprator suggest to use the make_password to update the password field in view...

```
form.crew_password=make_password(crew_password)
form.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this method of making.

Add this is your model

from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

```
  class Crew(models.Model):
    
        crew_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        crew_code = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, unique=True)
        crew_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
        crew_password = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.password = make_password(self.password)
        super(Crew, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This working for me .

Thanks